# unable to upgrade zoom on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, pacman, aur

I've got zoom installed on my `Arch` box. When I start it, it shows me a window which states on the bottom `Version: 3.5.374815.0324`. The problem is, I don't remember how I got this original version installed. I tried `sudo pacman -R zoom` which gives me `error: target not found: zoom`, the same with `yay -R zoom`. It also does not show up inder `zoom -Q`.

I downloaded the latest version from https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_c0913442-0832-428d-aa15-b004b80cfafe and tried to install it with `sudo pacman -U zoom_x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` and while it first says:

```
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) zoom-5.0.399860.0429-1

Total Installed Size:  150.29 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

, after confirmation with `Y` I get:

```
...
zoom: /opt/zoom/zoom.sh exists in filesystem
zoom: /opt/zoom/zoomlinux exists in filesystem
zoom: /opt/zoom/zopen exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/bin/zoom exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/mime/packages/zoom.xml exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/pixmaps/Zoom.png exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/pixmaps/application-x-zoom.png exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Hoe do I get these files overwritten and `zoom` upgraded to the newer version?

**Update**

I moved `/opt/zoom/ to /opt/zoom~/` and a retried but got:

```
$ sudo pacman -U zoom_x86_64.pkg.tar.xz 
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) zoom-5.0.399860.0429-1

Total Installed Size:  150.29 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                                    [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                                  [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                                       [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                                 [##########################################################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
zoom: /usr/bin/zoom exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/mime/packages/zoom.xml exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/pixmaps/Zoom.png exists in filesystem
zoom: /usr/share/pixmaps/application-x-zoom.png exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

upon which I moved each of these files  like so:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/zoom /usr/bin/zoom~
$ sudo mv /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop /usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop~
$ sudo mv /usr/share/mime/packages/zoom.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/zoom.xml~
$ sudo mv /usr/share/pixmaps/Zoom.png /usr/share/pixmaps/Zoom.png~
$ sudo mv /usr/share/pixmaps/application-x-zoom.png /usr/share/pixmaps/application-x-zoom.png~
$ sudo pacman -U zoom_x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

I then reinstalled andit seemed to complete:

```
...
:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                                    [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                                  [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                                       [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                                 [##########################################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                                               [##########################################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) installing zoom                                                                                                                             [##########################################################################################] 100%
run post install script, action is 5.0.399860.0429-1...
Error in file "/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kdeconnect_open.desktop": "*/*" is an invalid MIME type ("*" is an unregistered media type)
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/3) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
(2/3) Updating the desktop file MIME type cache...
(3/3) Updating the MIME type database...
```

but when I then launched zoom, I still got a dialog that reads **Version: 3.5.374815.0324**

So it didn't actually upgrade....

or the package doesn't actually consist a newer version....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I deleted the directory & files I had renamed previously and then installed zoom with `yay -S zoom` which got me version **5.0.933860.0429**

Comment: what directory & files?

Comment: The ones listed above:
`/usr/bin/zoom`
`/usr/share/applications/Zoom.desktop`


`/usr/share/mime/packages/zoom.xml` `/usr/share/pixmaps/application-x-zoom.png` and
`/usr/share/pixmaps/Zoom.png`

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is to run:

```
sudo pacman -U --overwrite '*' zoom_x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

which should cause pacman to overwrite the existing files. However, `--overwrite '*'` is not recommended, as it can be dangerous. So, it might be a safer option to just move or delete the existing files/folders manually (since there aren't too many).